# Using Mobile Ads SDK with IONIC

Tags: android, ionic-framework, googleads-mobile-unity

I'm making an hibrid App using Ionic, Angular and Capacitor.

I need to use the Google Mobile Ads SDK to show banners. I try with the AdMob plugin for capacitor, but it lacks of Native Ads, that are the main core of my App.

I added the SDK directly in Android Studio but I don't know which files I have to edit to insert the banners in the right position.

It's possible using this approach, or I have to try others possibilities?

Comment: What is the Issue with AdMob plugin ?

Comment: I can't use native ads, I didn't see it on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You cant have NATIVE ADS on Ionic solution, because the Webview schema.

Some plugin use a absolute position to have native, but the scroll is very bad.